# SQL Server - NULL vs blank in IF condition - ISNULL vs COALESCE

Tags: null, coalesce, isnull

I am expecting ELSE part to be printed in this case. But it doesn't. It works if the input is blank `''`. But for `null`, it fails. Even with `ISNULL` and `COALESCE`, it is same. Could you please explain the logic?

```
DECLARE @V_MY_VAR VARCHAR(50) = NULL;
IF ISNULL(@V_MY_VAR,'X') = 'HELLO'
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'INSIDE IF - '+ @V_MY_VAR;
    END;
ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'INSIDE ELSE - '+ @V_MY_VAR;
    END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your variable is null, you can't concat it with the string in your if or else clause.
You must remove it...

```
DECLARE @V_MY_VAR VARCHAR(50) = NULL;
IF ISNULL(@V_MY_VAR,'X') = 'HELLO'
BEGIN
    PRINT 'INSIDE IF - ';
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'INSIDE ELSE - ';
END;
```

...or replace it by a non null value, as example using your propose ISNULL.

```
DECLARE @V_MY_VAR VARCHAR(50) = NULL;
IF ISNULL(@V_MY_VAR,'X') = 'HELLO'
BEGIN
    PRINT 'INSIDE IF - '+ ISNULL(@V_MY_VAR,1);
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'INSIDE ELSE - '+ ISNULL(@V_MY_VAR,2);
END;
```

You can test this here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1cd76deb1cf126626999855bd5bc1061)